# Drupal 8 custom module getting page not found

Tags: drupal-8

i'm trying to learn Drupal 8, i've been following the official guide to create a custom module ([this tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules)), but when i go to the /hello route i get a page not found error, the module is active, maybe an error with the routing?

here's part of the code:

hello_world.routing.yml

```
hello_world.content:
  path: '/hello'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\hello_world\Controller\HelloController::content'
    _title: 'Hello World'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access content'
```

this is the HelloController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\hello_world\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;

/**
 * Defines HelloController class.
 */
class HelloController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Display the markup.
   *
   * @return array
   *   Return markup array.
   */
  public function content() {
    return [
      '#type' => 'markup',
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
    ];
  }

}
```

And this is the directory structure

[image]

I'm new with drupal so it is really posible that i made a rookie mistake, any help would be helpful, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your routing file says hello_worl, it is a typo. Correct that and clear caches.

Comment: Cool, your screenshot was the answer :)